# Filter a list of lists based on the first two items of the sublist - natural language processing with NLTK

Tags: python, nltk

I have generated a list of trigrams and their frequencies in NLTK with this code

```
tokens = nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(docs)
from nltk.collocations import *
trigram_measures = nltk.collocations.TrigramAssocMeasures()
finderT = TrigramCollocationFinder.from_words(tokens)
scoredT = finderT.score_ngrams(trigram_measures.raw_freq)
```

Given a user defined 'input' of two words, I want to filer the list scoredT to return those values where the input matches the first two items of the sub list in scoredT

scoredT looks like this

```
[(('out', 'to', 'the'), 2.7147650642313413e-05),
(('proud', 'of', 'you'), 2.7147650642313413e-05)]
```

So if input were equal to 'out to', Id like to filter the list to return 'the'

I tried

```
matches = filter(scoredT[0:len(scoredT)][0:1]==input, scoredT)
```

but get the following error TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

Comment: `filter(function, iterable)`, I think you have a boolean expression instead of a function. Try a `lambda` instead.

Comment: I think you're looking for the NgramModel functionality that hasn't been fixed yet: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/1351

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scoredT[0:len(scoredT)][0:1]==input` compares the *first* element of `scoredT` to `input`. So it will be boolean. Then you pass it to `filter`, which requires the first argument to be a *boolean valued function*, hence your error. The pythonic way:

```
matches = [(trigram, score) for (trigram, score) in scoredT if trigram[:2] == input]
```

Also you need to make sure that `input` is a tuple.